# laravel breeze authentication failed in request file but it's returns authenticated user in controller

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, breeze

I'm using Laravel breeze as the back end and nextjs in front end.

First I login to site and every thing is correct.

When trying to insert a new order, in OrderRequest file I Check if the user is authenticated or not :

```
public function authorize()
{
    if(!Auth::check())
        return false;
}
```

this method always return false but if I bypass the authentication process and always return true and go to controller I can get the authenticated user info.

Why this happened? If the user is authenticated I have to recognize the user status in all sections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem, Just by adding `return true` at the end of the method:

```
public function authorize()
{
    if(!Auth::check())
        return false;
    return true;
}
```